# strange file buffer size in chromium

Tags: c++, io, chromium, ifstream

Reading chromium sources, found  [this interesting code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/base/files/file_util.cc#52) for comparing content of two files. The interesting part is stack allocated buffer size:

```
  const int BUFFER_SIZE = 2056;
  char buffer1[BUFFER_SIZE], buffer2[BUFFER_SIZE];
  do {
    file1.read(buffer1, BUFFER_SIZE);
    file2.read(buffer2, BUFFER_SIZE);

    if ((file1.eof() != file2.eof()) ||
        (file1.gcount() != file2.gcount()) ||
        (memcmp(buffer1, buffer2, static_cast<size_t>(file1.gcount())))) {
      file1.close();
      file2.close();
      return false;
    }   
  } while (!file1.eof() || !file2.eof());
```

The first question is why so interesting buffer size is chosen? `git blame` shows nothing interesting regarding this. The only guess I have is that this particular buffer size `2056 = 2048 + 8` is supposed to induce read ahead behavior from a such high abstraction point. In other words, the logic is something like this: on first part read we will get one full buffer of 2048 plus 8. And if internal system IO buffer size is 2048, then extra 8 bytes will induce reading of next block. And when we will call next part read, next buffer will be already fetched by implementation and so on by induction.

The second question is why exactly 2048 is chosen as ubiquitous buffer size? Why not something like `PAGE_SIZE` or `BUFSIZE`?

Comment: Probably cargo cult programming. I'd be surprised if that produced better throughput than reading 2048 bytes at a time.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I do not want to believe in possibility of cargo cult programming in chromium especially in something cornerstone like a work with files :(

Comment: @user1641854 Explicitly closing a `std::ifstream` and passing `std::ios::in` to its constructor are both from the cult of "I'd better do this manually, just in case".

Comment: @molbdnilo, std::ios::in has to be explicitly defined because  std::ios::binary is not part of default argument for openmode. Albeit, explicit resource management is strange thing for RAII(close in ifstream).

Comment: @user1641854 The constructor adds that flag.

Comment: @molbdnilo, yes, 27.9.1.7 basic_ifstream constructors clause 2: `rdbuf()->open(s, mode | ios_base::in)`. Didn't know it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked chromium devel mail list and here are some answers:

> Scott Hess shess@chromium.org
>
> I doubt there was any reason other than that the buffer needs to have
>   some size.  I'd have chosen 4096, myself, since most filesystem block
>   sizes are that these days.  But iostream already has internal
>   buffering so it's not super important.

So it seems no particular reason for exactly this buffer size.